# CSS responsive : Resizing windows VS Chrome responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

Here's my problem. It's kinda basic but it really irritates me. I've made a responsive web page that looks really great when resizing the window manually but doesn't look so great when using the responsive tool embedded in chrome. So i decided to design according to what it looks like on Google Chrome responsive tool, but now it looks awful when i resize the window manually.

Which one should i trust ?! How do i know what i'll looks like on mobile ?

Edit : Also, i have this basic rule

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 900px) {

   body {
      width: 60%;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }

}
```

The body width will correctly resize while using chrome responsive tool, but will not when resizing chrome window. If i change it for `min-width : 900px`, the body will correctly resize while resizing chrome window but not with chrome responsive tool !

Edit 2 : Picture to explain what i mean

On the left this is the responsive inspector tool provided by Chrome, on the right this is the chrome windows being resized ( both are the same width ) while using `@media only screen and (min-device-width: 900px)` 
The media query doesn't work here ( on the inspector ) but does work while resizing the windows
[image]

Same thing here but using `@media only screen and (min-width: 900px)`. The inspector tool displays the page Ok, but whenever i resize the Chrome window the query doesnt get triggered !

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a live example of your work? I am not sure which difficulties you are facing exactly

Comment: Refresh the page after a window resize.

Comment: If possible could you share live link of the website ?

Comment: @Scott: Media query doesnt need a refresh to apply their CSS rules.

Comment: @Sayed Rafeeq: No i can't. As you can see it's a local version.

Comment: @Jorel Amthor: Yeah you can do it, upload the images on image hosting website and add your code into jsfiddle. Share demo code link.

Comment: @SayedRafeeq arent the screenshot enough ? Left is Chrome device inspector, right is a Chrome window being resized. First screen shot is using min-device-width, 2nd screenshot is using min-width

Comment: @Jorel Amthor:  We can configured out the issue by seeing in multiple browsers.

Comment: If you say so @JorelAmthor apparently my milage varies.. but I won't belabor the point.

Comment: @Scott i dont say so, it's the way it is. Try to resize http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries this page for example, you see the element moving around without refreshing the page...

Comment: As I stated.. I'm not going to belabor the issue. Good luck with your problem. I hope you get it solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should target your Web Page responsiveness for Windows Size Rather than Device Width.

Change Every Min-device-width and max-device-width to min-width and max-width respectively. This should solve your problem. I have the same problem while scaling with responsive design mode and window resizing. It got solved after making this small change in CSS Media Query.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change "only screen" to "all", because Chrome can use "handheld" media for iPhone emulation and change "min-device-width" to "min-width".

Comment: Nope, still got the same problem ( see screen shots )